# How to make mountebank use all the CPUs in a system for load testing

Tags: mountebank

If mountebank is put in a production or staging server to load test the application, do we need to configure mb to use all the cpus of the system?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, mountebank uses non blocking I/O rather than multiple threads. If you need to scale it beyond what one instance can handle, put multiple instances behind a load balancer sharing the same test data.

Comment: Hi Brandon. Yesterday I purchased your book. Nice book (though it could improve :P). In chapter 10, it uses Gatling for load testing. Gatling uses multiple threads/CPUs right? Can you please tell me that?